Properly handle TransformStream on EventSource.close()
I'm trying to set up a SSE mechanism on my NextJS app to send messages from the backend to the client while some data processing is happening on the server.
I have setup a route endpoint like so:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import uploadProgressStream from '@/lib/sseWriter';
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const progressStreamReadable: ReadableStream = uploadProgressStream.getReadableStream();
  const progressStreamWritable: WritableStreamDefaultWriter = uploadProgressStream.getWritableStream();

  req.signal.onabort = async () => {
    console.log('sse connection aborted');
// progressStreamWritable.close()
// progressStreamReadable.getReader().releaseLock();
    return new NextResponse(null);
  };

  return new NextResponse(progressStreamReadable, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      Connection: 'keep-alive',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-transform',
    },
  });
}

For the stream that serves as the writing stream for the backend, I have implemented a singleton, more or less, to ensure that the route and the backend are referencing the same stream and deal with the same data. But I'm not sure if this is necessary:
class UploadProgressStream {
    private streamInstance = new TransformStream();
    private streamWriter: WritableStreamDefaultWriter;
    private streamReader: ReadableStream;

    constructor() {
        this.streamInstance = new TransformStream();
        this.streamWriter = this.streamInstance.writable.getWriter();
        this.streamReader = this.streamInstance.readable;
    }

    getStreamInstance(): TransformStream {
        return this.streamInstance;
    }

    getWritableStream(): WritableStreamDefaultWriter {
        return this.streamWriter;
    }

    getReadableStream(): ReadableStream {
        return this.streamReader;
    }

    async writeToStream(
        fileName: string,
        totalSize: number,
        imported: number
      ) {
        const message = JSON.stringify({
          [fileName]: { totalSize, imported }
        });
        this.streamWriter.ready
            .then(() => {
                this.streamWriter.write(`data: ${message}\n\n`);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
            console.log("writer.ready error", e);
            });
    }
}

const uploadProgressStream = new UploadProgressStream();
export default uploadProgressStream;  

Now, in the client, I just do const eventSource = new EventSource('/api/sse'); when the file processing starts.
When the file processing ends due to resolves Promises in the client, I want to close the eventSource simply with a eventSource.close() but I feel like I have to take something measures regarding the stream when receiving the abort signal in the route. I feel like I have to close and/or unlock some of the streams as my try of uncommencted lines are suggesting.
However, I'm totally unsure what to do exactly as I'm receiving different errors for different things I tried.
If I go like the above get I get the following error after 2 or 3 rounds of file processing.
⨯ TypeError: Response body object should not be disturbed or locked

Any suggestion what to do on the abort signal, or, is this approach even valid at all?
